# sql error when writing pm

Tags: mysql, phpbb

I am having trouble with sql error when writing a pm on my forum. It is phpbb.
An here is the error i get.

> > SQL ERROR [ mysql4 ] 
> >     Duplicate entry 'notification.type.pm' for key 'type' [1062]

**SQL**

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_notification_types (notification_type_name, notification_type_enabled) 
VALUES ('notification.type.pm', 1)
```

**BACKTRACE**

> FILE: (not given by php) LINE: (not given by php) CALL: msg_handler()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/driver.php LINE: 855 CALL:
>   trigger_error()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/mysql.php LINE: 181 CALL:
>   phpbb\db\driver\driver->sql_error()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/factory.php LINE: 329 CALL:
>   phpbb\db\driver\mysql->sql_query()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/notification/manager.php LINE: 956 CALL:
>   phpbb\db\driver\factory->sql_query()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/notification/type/base.php LINE: 133 CALL:
>   phpbb\notification\manager->get_notification_type_id()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/notification/manager.php LINE: 909 CALL:
>   phpbb\notification\type\base->set_notification_manager()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/notification/manager.php LINE: 885 CALL:
>   phpbb\notification\manager->load_object()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/notification/manager.php LINE: 353 CALL:
>   phpbb\notification\manager->get_item_type_class()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/includes/functions_privmsgs.php LINE: 1936 CALL:
>   phpbb\notification\manager->add_notifications()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/includes/ucp/ucp_pm_compose.php LINE: 862 CALL:
>   submit_pm()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/includes/ucp/ucp_pm.php LINE: 108 CALL: compose_pm()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/includes/functions_module.php LINE: 674 CALL:
>   ucp_pm->main()
>
> FILE: [ROOT]/ucp.php LINE: 369 CALL: p_master->load_active()

Comment: There is a unique index on **notification.type.pm** and also a row with id 1 or field has no auto_increment. please post the output from **show create table phpbb_notification_types**

Comment: It would appear table phpbb_notification_types  has a unique constraint on notification_type_name limiting it to only one occurance.  so 'notification.type.pm' already exists in the table.  Possible errors in code: you're executing the SQL statmeent twice causing a duplicate, the value already existed and your not checking.  you could add a check to ensure it doens't exist before the update and if it does the update just returns success though no record is inserted.

Comment: You should probably be using `UPDATE` to change the row, not `INSERT`. Or maybe `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.